# Let g(x) be the Mclaurin's expansion of sin(2x). If error is atmost $\frac{1250. 10^{-4}}{3} $ for x $\in$ $ [0,\frac{1}{2}]$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Let g(x) be the Mclaurin's expansion of sin(2x). If error is atmost $\frac{1250. 10^{-4}}{3} $ for x $\in$ $ [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ . Then minimum number of non zero terms in g is

A.2

B.3

C.4

D.5

I use formula for remainder term if taylor series which is in this case is

$$R_n(x) =  \frac {f^{n+1}(c) x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$ . i put $c = 1/2$ and i get equality as $(n+1)! < 24$. which is satisfied by $n=2$. I am not sure however

Thanks

Comment: What is $(n+!)$?

Comment: @user21820 .(n+!) was a typo in th last line. I fixed it to (n+1).............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning about the remainder is incorrect.

Using Taylor expansion you get $\sin(2x) = 2x - \frac{1}{6} (2x)^3 + \sin^{(4)}(c) \frac{1}{24} (2x)^4$ for **some** $c \in [0,x]$, given any $x \in [0,0.5]$, and you can't assume that it is any particular value. Indeed in this instance it turns out that it is never $0.5$ even if $x = 0.5$. The bottom line is that if your choice isn't the correct one, then it's irrelevant to your goal of finding the minimum number of non-zero terms necessary to achieve the error bounds.

Instead, what you should do is to first check that **if** you use $2$ non-zero terms, **then** the error is at most $\frac{1}{24}$ because $\sin^{(4)}(c) \le 1$ for any real $c$ and $(2x)^4 \le 1$ for any $x \in [0,0.5]$. Therefore the minimum number of non-zero terms necessary to achieve the desired error bound of $\frac{1}{24}$ is **at most** $2$.

After that, you **still need to** check that you cannot achieve the desired error bound with **less** non-zero terms. That would be to use either $0$ terms, giving $\sin(2x) \approx 0$, or $1$ term, giving $\sin(2x) \approx 2x$. In both cases you must explicitly prove that there is some $x$ where the approximation is not as desired. For example, if $x = 0.4$ then both approximations are off by more than $\frac{1}{24}$. Therefore we conclude that having less than $2$ terms is not enough.

Since we have shown both that $2$ terms is enough, but less than $2$ terms is not enough, we have proven that $2$ is the minimum number of terms needed.

Also, the convention is to use "$f^{(k)}$" to denote the $k$-th derivative of $f$, because "$f^k$" denotes the $k$-th iterate of $f$ instead.